# How to create a response for a Ajax query to a Django View such that the objects can be iterated in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have the following ajax function in my view

```
def load_parts(request):
    machinery_group_id  = request.GET.get('machinery_group')
    parts = MachineryPart.objects.filter(machinery_group =machinery_group_id)
    return HttpResponse(parts)
```

I am trying to iterate to this response in my template using

```
      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'machinery_group': groupId 
        },
        success: function (parts) {
      alert(typeof parts)  
      {% for part in parts %}        
        //Do Something  here
        {% endfor %}
```

I the View, I have tried

1. Serialising parts using serializer and return a JSON,
2. Return the parts query set as a value()/value_list(), with and without serialising
3. Just return the parts as is.

In each case, the typeof is a string, and I am unable to iterate over the parts returned in the template to get the individual part objects.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? (go with the second answer if you're not using partials) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306649/how-to-loop-ajax-response-data-in-django-template-language/59307036#59307036

Comment: I am not using partials. With the second response, I am required to serialise the queryset object, and it becomes non iterable.

Comment: It worked using partials. Thanks